# Generics with interfaces in F#

Tags: f#, interface, generics

In C# one can state that a generic parameter must implement a certain interface like so:

```
public class Something<T> where T : IComparable
{
    ...
}
```

How does one specify this in F#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generic constraints use "when" in F#:

```
type Foo<'a when 'a :> IComparable> = 
  member x.Bla = 0
```