# Does F# support templates or Generics?

Tags: f#

I want to implement a heap data structure and want to apply the code to any type that supports comparison, i.e. < = > <= >= operations.

How to do this in F# as it is statically typed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does, but you have to annotate as follows:

```
type Thing<'a when 'a:comparison> =
    | Pair of ('a*'a)
    with 
      member m.InOrder() = 
        match m with
        | Pair (a,b) when a<=b -> true
        | _ -> false
      member m.Equal() =
        match m with 
        | Pair (a,b) when a=b -> true
        | _ -> false

Pair(1,2).InOrder() //true
Pair(3,2).InOrder() //false
Pair(42,42).Equal() //true
```

Try replacing `Thing<'a when 'a:comparison>` by `Thing<'a when 'a:equality>` to watch the `InOrder()` method fail, while `Equal()` still works. Replace `Thing<'a when 'a:comparison>` by `Thing<'a>` and both methods won't work.

Answer (score 5):

For more on the specific cases of equality and comparison constraints, see

http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1621.entry

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does support generics - look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770143/generics-with-interfaces-in-f) as an example.